# Different Response Port than Request - JMeter TCP Sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am using TCP Sampler in JMeter. I am trying to test a application which accept request on 5000 port but send response on 5001. How can we configure JMeter to accept response on different port than request?

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 TCP Samplers, one for sending the request and another one is for reading the response.

In order to avoid "endless" waiting for the response of the TCP Sampler which will send the request set the reasonable timeout

[image]

The sampler will appear as failed in the results, you can use [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to "expect" this failure and to mark the request as passed:

[image]